# Java Web platform for data analysis

Tags: java, php, mysql, spring

I am working on a data analytics project and I built my website with Laravel (PHP).

However, I am now required to :

1. analyze the massive amount of data from the database
2. Keep a lot of in-memory objects
3. have a system running 24/7 analyzing and processing data

I don't believe that PHP is best suited for this task and was thinking of using java instead ( use it as an API that will process the data and return the results to my website for viewing). It will have to run on a server.

These are some types of data analysis that I need to do :

Retrieve 10,000 plus records from MySQL and hold. Analyze the data for patterns. Build models from the data. Analyze graphs

I have never used any JAVA services/frameworks online and was wondering what is best suited for my task. What I came across was :

Spring

Jersey

Comment: You're probably right that PHP isn't the right too, but why Java?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to combine Apache storm + spring framework to resolve your problem. I am currently working on the similar project as yours.

Comment: this looks like a comment

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar troubles before, not advertising, and later used other people recommended FineReport, it is based on a Java web report software, can do a lot of dataset data analysis, and support MYSQL and other databases, you can try ~